# K-means, knee locator, not quite correct

Tags: python, machine-learning, cluster-analysis, k-means

Using some codes I found here and in google, I have made a kmeans clustering algorithem based on Knee. locator:

```
def kmeans_clustering(data_set: pd.DataFrame, column: str, clusters_count: int):
    '''K means clustering on dataframe, choosing specific columns and cluster count'''
    data_set = data_set[column].to_numpy()
    data_values = data_set.reshape(-1, 1)
    kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=clusters_count).fit(data_values)
    y = kmeans.fit_predict(data_values)  # prediction of k
    frame = pd.DataFrame(y, index=data_set.index)
    frame.index = frame.index[frame.index.isin(data_set.index)]
    return frame.join(data_set)

wcss =[]
    for i in range(1, 11):
        kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=i, init='k-means++', max_iter=300, n_init=10, random_state=0)
        kmeans.fit(RTN)
        wcss.append(kmeans.inertia_)
    kn = KneeLocator(
                        range(1, 11), wcss,  # put range in variable
                        curve='convex',
                        direction='decreasing', interp_method='interp1d')
```

............

```
for i in RTN:
    frame = kmeans_clustering(data_set=RTN, column= val, clusters_count= kn.knee)
```

............

My dataframe is "RTN". Columns represnted by "val" (has around thousand). After running the code I get the following warning:

```
ConvergenceWarning: Number of distinct clusters (3) found smaller than n_clusters (4). Possibly due to duplicate points in X.
  kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=clusters_count).fit(data_values)
C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\sklearn\cluster\_kmeans.py:1122: ConvergenceWarning: Number of distinct clusters (3) found smaller than n_clusters (4). Possibly due to duplicate points in X.
  return self.fit(X, sample_weight=sample_weight).labels_
```

I understand that I possibly have done a "double operation", but where did it go wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I think you haven't gone wrong. It just means, that KMeans did not find enough clusters. You know, KMeans chooses a number of data points in your set to build clusters. Then it assigns the rest of the points to these clusters and calculates the "center" of these clusters, then it assgins again all points to the nearest center and so on until there is no change anymore.

During this process it might happen, that the data points assigned to one cluster all get "captured" by other clusters nearby, so that the number of clusters gets smaller. This strongly depends on the initial choice of your data points with which clustering is started.

So you can try to set the random_state parameter to see, if you can get the desired number of clusters. If you use that parameter, you could also do a small number of runs with the same cluster size and take the best clustering you get for each cluster_size (the smallest `inertia_`). You might also want to play around with the `init` parameter.

Here an example:
[image: Example data set]

Immagine, you want to have the points clustered in four clusters. If you are unlucky the random selection used the four red points. With this setup in the intial step it is almost certain, that the 3 single points in the middle are added to one cluster while the three outer structures will get their own cluster. So after the first clustering step the inner cluster (with the three inner points) will be assigned to a point in the middle of these 3 points, but at the same time the middle point of the outer clusters will move towards the three points as well and it might end up that the middle points are then closer to the middle of the outer clusters as to their own cluster and so will be "captured" by the outer clusters, which results in the inner cluster to contain no more points and disappear.

Comment: Thanks  for responding. If not to changing anything, may I still relay on the result? or should I just try another  algorithm? and the second issue, the part after "wcss" is bothering me as I pick up a number between 1-11 in n_clusters and then I use knee to find the right n_clusters which I use in the for loop as kn.knee.

Comment: TBH, I am not sure that my code does the right operation as I have used "i" as detection of number of clusters to choose Knee from, and then Knee method which used in the def itself.

Comment: I haven't used `KneeLocator` yet myself, but from the api doku your call looks good. Have you already plotted the curve? is there a clear "knee" in it? if anything is wrong, then it is more likely that it has to do with your data. E.g. too view distinct points etc. If you have the data in a pandas datarame, you can try `drop_duplicates()` on it to see, how many different data points you really have. Your parameter `n_init=10` already makes KMeans try 10 times to get a good clustering, but I think that doesn't mean that it is guaranteed to select a clustering with `n_clusters`, ...

Comment: ...because there might be Clusterings with less clusters and a lower `intertia_` (resulting from an effect as mentioned above). But if you apply knee to a curve that contains two or more consecutive values with the same number of clusters, knee might be mislead and detect a "knee". So I would suggest to set `n_init` to 1 and add a loop with tries and select the best yourself with the constraint, that the actual number of clusters found equals `n_clusters`

Comment: You are right, there are many identical points in my data, but I do the K means on every column seperatly, is it right to use it if I have only 3 or 4 different points per column ?

Comment: Why do you use it separately for each column? I think the identical points are the cause for the problem. You should rather remove the duplicates and use the `sample_weight` keyword to pass the number of identical points to compensate that. Otherwise it is no surprise some of your clusters get initialized with the same point.

Comment: Each column has it's own expression. I understand that the random points actually was created in the same point